# Render has chunks of black, apparently missing information

Tags: rendering

I am a blender novice. As an experiment, I have created a 2 second animation of a rotating die and exported it as an mp4. Looking at the animation in the layout tab, it looks exactly how I want it, but the mp4 looks terrible. There are large chunks of the image which render as black - it appears as if the rendering engine can't handle lighting around the edge of my object (maybe).

[image]

I've tried changing every setting I can come up with in the rendering panel (I've even tried rendering a png) and I always get the same result - horrible blacked-out chunks. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why this wasn't working, but I was able to resolve it by going to the render properties tab and changing the render engine in the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other objects that could be overlapping the die? It looks as if there is a face in the same position as the face of the die. It may be hidden in viewport but visible in renders.